# Is it possible in javascript regex, to match string inside the string matched by my capture group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string `dfed  operator  11 -  145`. I am trying to match string `operator  11` and inside this matched string, i am trying to match string `11`. Currently I successfully matched `operator 11` with regex `((O|o)perator(i|I)?\s*)\d+(?=\s*(-|_)\s*\d+)`. As I am in javascript, I can not use lookbehinds.

Is my approach correct? Is there any way to accomplish this in regex? How can i match string `11` inside previously matched string `operator  11`?

Thank you

Comment: Enclose the first `\d+` in another group? `(\d+)`?

Comment: If you use `s.match(/.../g)`, see [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you provide demo of what you mean? Thank you

Comment: @PoulBak If OP uses `match` with `g`, OP won't have the access to captured values. Thus, OP must learn how to do it, hence the link is provided.

Comment: Just replace the first `\d+` with `(\d+)`. eg `((O|o)perator(i|I)?\s*)(\d+)(?=\s*(-|_)\s*\d+)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Please see your example: https://regex101.com/r/xBUaFn/1  It matches whole `operator  11`. I want to match `11` inside  `operator  11`. Is it possible to accomplish this via regex?

Comment: No, look at "Group 4". Group 4 is *exactly* `11` and nothing else, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am confused. How do i "look"  at capture group 4 `\d+)`?

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your regex by creating a group for the first `number` in the matched `string`:

```js
const str = 'dfed  operator  11 -  145';
const regex = /([O|o]perator)[i|I]?\s*(\d+)*[?=\s*(-|_)\s*\d+]/;
const found = str.match(regex);

console.log(found);
console.log(found[1]); // <-- group for string
console.log(found[2]); // <-- group for number
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to accomplish this with regex? not to use mach twice?

Comment: How would you get the same result with one call of `match`?

Comment: Check the updated answer.. And just for you to know i have not downvoted your question

Comment: Updated answer using `match` only one time

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have upvoted your answer. Is there any way to mach string inside the substring matched by certain capturing group? Would this be correct approach?

Comment: Edited answer according to this last comment to get the `string` and the `number` by adding the respective groups..

Answer (score 0):

You could use (mind the case insensitive flag in the demo):

```
operator\D+(\d+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/3hCexe/1/).